# Banner flash error when browsing on a website

Tags: flash, joomla, banner, joomla3.0

I am doing a website with Joomla 3.1. I use a flash banner which has to be on every page of the main menu. For this, I have created a personalized module in the banner configuration part of Joomla. Here's a picture :

[image]

The flash script `header.swf` is a slide animation of different pictures (where `custom.xml` contains the path of the images). As you can see, I had to add JavaScript code in personal code section. In this snippet, I call the flash animation with parameters.

My issue is that flash animation only works on the home page.

It also works when I reload this home page. When I try to browse on all others pages (of the main menu), the flash crashes with the following error :

```
Debugger :
[IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032"]
```

I have not experienced this problem with the older version.

On this version, you will see that flash animation is reloaded fine when you go on another page of the menu. What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by setting absolute URL for custom.xml because I go into subfolders when I browse on website.